# Trying to make World Cup Group Stage draw

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures

I took so long time trying to make a **UEFA Champions League Group Stage draw** by JavaScript, I tried about 5~7 algorithms and all of them failed (meaning it may success but not always due to shuffling and random picking),

I was frustrated and gave up trying, but months later, I tried to make a **FIFA World Cup draw**, and same same, but I noticed that one of the algorithms I tried in WC, when I tried it in CL it succeeded!

I think the reason this happens because CL rules are steady and clear (every group has team from each pot, and not from the same association) but the WC is a little more complex (also every group has team from each pot, and not from the same confederation),

but the problem I encountered from UEFA teams (Every group should have at least one UEFA team and not more than two, [5 groups have two and 3 groups have one from any various pot]),

so my algorithm cannot deal with this dynamic rules.

I explain my algorithm with some examples:

From each pot and each team (after shuffling each pot),

looping every team I get the available groups for that team which matching the rules, and the available groups for every next team (if there are),

Then search for number of teams have the identical available groups,

for example:

Current team available groups: [1, 4]

Team 2 available groups: [4]

this means group 4 is blocked because it's the only possible group to team 2.

Another example:

Current team available groups: [1, 3, 4]

Team 2 available groups: [1, 3]

Team 3 available groups: [1, 2, 3, 4]

Team 4 available groups: [1, 3]

this means group 1 and 3 are blocked because one for team 2 and the other for team 4

(Also if there are three teams with the same 3 available groups, so the all 3 groups are blocked, and so on)

Champions league code which is ok:

```
Array.prototype.randomIndex = function () {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * this.length);
};
Array.prototype.random = function () {
  return this[this.randomIndex()];
};
Array.prototype.shuffle = function () {
  return this.sort(() => Math.random() - .5);
};
const pots   = [[{"name":"Real Madrid","country":"Spain"},{"name":"Eintracht Frankfurt","country":"Germany"},{"name":"Manchester City","country":"England"},{"name":"AC Milan","country":"Italy"},{"name":"Bayern München","country":"Germany"},{"name":"Paris Saint-Germain","country":"France"},{"name":"FC Porto","country":"Portugal"},{"name":"Ajax","country":"Netherlands"}],[{"name":"Liverpool","country":"England"},{"name":"Chelsea","country":"England"},{"name":"FC Barcelona","country":"Spain"},{"name":"Juventus","country":"Italy"},{"name":"Atlético Madrid","country":"Spain"},{"name":"Sevilla","country":"Spain"},{"name":"RB Leipzig","country":"Germany"},{"name":"Tottenham Hotspur","country":"England"}],[{"name":"Borussia Dortmund","country":"Germany"},{"name":"FC Salzburg","country":"Austria"},{"name":"Shakhtar Donetsk","country":"Ukraine"},{"name":"Internazionale","country":"Italy"},{"name":"Napoli","country":"Italy"},{"name":"Benfica","country":"Portugal"},{"name":"Sporting CP Lisbon","country":"Portugal"},{"name":"Bayer Leverkusen","country":"Germany"}],[{"name":"Glasgow Rangers","country":"Scotland"},{"name":"Dinamo Zagreb","country":"Croatia"},{"name":"Olympique Marseille","country":"France"},{"name":"FC København","country":"Denmark"},{"name":"Club Brugge","country":"Belgium"},{"name":"Celtic","country":"Scotland"},{"name":"Viktoria Plzen","country":"Czechia"},{"name":"Maccabi Haifa","country":"Israel"}]];
const groups = new Array(8).fill().map(() => new Array(4));
function getAvailable(team, pot, execlude = null) {
  let availableGroups = groups.filter(g => g != execlude && g.every(t => !pot.includes(t)));
  availableGroups = availableGroups.filter(g => g.every(t => t.country != team.country));
  return availableGroups;
}
function getAvailableGroups(teams, pot) {
  let availableGroups = getAvailable(teams[0], pot);
  if (availableGroups.length == 1) return availableGroups;
  let available = [];
  checking: for (let group of availableGroups) {
    let leftNextAvailableGroups = teams.slice(1).map(t => getAvailable(t, pot, group));
    if (leftNextAvailableGroups.find(ag => !ag.length)) continue checking;
    let freeGroups = new Set;
    for (let nextTeamAvailableGroups of leftNextAvailableGroups) {
      if (nextTeamAvailableGroups.length == 1 && nextTeamAvailableGroups.includes(group)) continue checking;
      let samePossibilites = leftNextAvailableGroups.filter(ag => ag.length == nextTeamAvailableGroups.length && ag.every((g, i) => g == nextTeamAvailableGroups[i]));
      if (samePossibilites.length == nextTeamAvailableGroups.length && samePossibilites[0].includes(group)) continue checking;
      if (availableGroups.some(g => leftNextAvailableGroups.filter(ag => ag.length == 1).includes(g))) continue checking;
      if (samePossibilites.length > nextTeamAvailableGroups.length) continue checking;
      nextTeamAvailableGroups.forEach(g => freeGroups.add(g));
    }
    if (freeGroups.size != teams.length - 1) continue checking;
    available.push(group);
  }
  return available;
}
pots.forEach(pot => pot.shuffle());
let p = 0;
for (let pot of pots) {
  for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    if (!p) {
      groups[i][0] = pot[i];
      continue;
    }
    let group = getAvailableGroups(pot.slice(i), pot).random();
    group[p] = pot[i];
  }
  p++;
}
```

World Cup code (If you keep reloading an error message will show in console saying `Ran out of possibilities`)

```
Array.prototype.shuffle = function () {
  return this.sort(() => Math.random() - .5);
};
const teams = [{"name":"Qatar","conf":"AFC"},{"name":"Brazil","conf":"CONMEBOL"},{"name":"Belgium","conf":"UEFA"},{"name":"France","conf":"UEFA"},{"name":"Argentina","conf":"CONMEBOL"},{"name":"England","conf":"UEFA"},{"name":"Spain","conf":"UEFA"},{"name":"Portugal","conf":"UEFA"},{"name":"Mexico","conf":"CONCACAF"},{"name":"Netherlands","conf":"UEFA"},{"name":"Denmark","conf":"UEFA"},{"name":"Germany","conf":"UEFA"},{"name":"Uruguay","conf":"CONMEBOL"},{"name":"Switzerland","conf":"UEFA"},{"name":"USA","conf":"CONCACAF"},{"name":"Croatia","conf":"UEFA"},{"name":"Senegal","conf":"CAF"},{"name":"IR Iran","conf":"AFC"},{"name":"Japan","conf":"AFC"},{"name":"Morocco","conf":"CAF"},{"name":"Serbia","conf":"UEFA"},{"name":"Poland","conf":"UEFA"},{"name":"Korea Republic","conf":"AFC"},{"name":"Tunisia","conf":"CAF"},{"name":"Cameroon","conf":"CAF"},{"name":"Canada","conf":"CONCACAF"},{"name":"Ecuador","conf":"CONMEBOL"},{"name":"Saudi Arabia","conf":"AFC"},{"name":"Ghana","conf":"CAF"},{"name":"Wales","conf":"UEFA"},{"name":"Costa Rica","conf":"CONCACAF"},{"name":"Australia","conf":"AFC"}];
const pots = [
  teams.slice(0, 8).sort((a, b) => {
    // Qatar automatically assigned to position A1
    if (a.name == "Qatar") return -1;
    if (b.name == "Qatar") return 1;
    return Math.random() - .5;
  }),
  teams.slice(8, 16).shuffle(),
  teams.slice(16, 24).shuffle(),
  teams.slice(24, 32).shuffle()
];
let g = 1;
let groups = Array(8).fill().map(() => Object.create(Array.prototype, {number: {value: g++}}));
let uefaLength = (a, t) => a + (t?.conf == "UEFA");
function getAvailable(team, pot, UEFACount, execlude = null) {
  let availableGroups = groups.filter(g => g != execlude && g.every(t => !pot.includes(t)));
  if (team.conf == "UEFA") {
    let f = 2 - (groups.filter(g => g.reduce(uefaLength, 0) == 2).length == UEFACount);
    availableGroups = availableGroups.filter(g => g.reduce(uefaLength, 0) < f);
  } else {
    availableGroups = availableGroups.filter(g => g.every(t => t.conf != team.conf));
  }
  return availableGroups;
}
function firstAvailableGroup(teams, pot, nextPots) {
  let availableGroups = getAvailable(teams[0], pot, 5);
  if (availableGroups.length == 1) return availableGroups[0];
  checking: for (let group of availableGroups) {
    let UEFACount = 5 - (teams[0].conf == "UEFA" && group.some(t => t.conf == "UEFA"));
    let leftNextAvailableGroups = teams.slice(1).map(t => getAvailable(t, pot, UEFACount, group));
    if (leftNextAvailableGroups.find(ag => !ag.length)) continue checking;
    let freeGroups = new Set;
    for (let nextTeamAvailableGroups of leftNextAvailableGroups) {
      if (nextTeamAvailableGroups.length == 1 && nextTeamAvailableGroups.includes(group)) continue checking;
      let samePossibilites = leftNextAvailableGroups.filter(ag => ag.length == nextTeamAvailableGroups.length && ag.every((g, i) => g == nextTeamAvailableGroups[i]));
      if (samePossibilites.length == nextTeamAvailableGroups.length && samePossibilites[0].includes(group)) continue checking;
      if (availableGroups.some(g => leftNextAvailableGroups.filter(ag => ag.length == 1).includes(g))) continue checking;
      if (samePossibilites.length > nextTeamAvailableGroups.length) continue checking;
      nextTeamAvailableGroups.forEach(g => freeGroups.add(g));
    }
    if (freeGroups.size != teams.length - 1) continue checking;
    for (let pot of nextPots) {
      let leftNextAvailableGroups = pot.map(t => getAvailable(t, pot, UEFACount));
      if (leftNextAvailableGroups.find(ag => !ag.length)) continue checking;
      let freeGroups = new Set;
      for (let nextTeamAvailableGroups of leftNextAvailableGroups) {
        if (!nextTeamAvailableGroups.length) continue checking;
        let samePossibilites = leftNextAvailableGroups.filter(ag => ag.length == nextTeamAvailableGroups.length && ag.every((g, i) => g == nextTeamAvailableGroups[i]));
        if (samePossibilites.length == nextTeamAvailableGroups.length && samePossibilites[0].includes(group)) continue checking;
        if (samePossibilites.length > nextTeamAvailableGroups.length) continue checking;
        nextTeamAvailableGroups.forEach(g => freeGroups.add(g));
      }
      if (freeGroups.size != 8) continue checking;
    }
    return group;
  }
}
let p = 0;
draw: for (let pot of pots) {
  for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    if (!p) {
      groups[i].push(pot[i]);
      continue;
    }
    let group = firstAvailableGroup(pot.slice(i), pot, pots.slice(p + 1));
    if (!group) {
      console.log(pots);
      console.error("ERROR!", [p, i], pot[i], groups);
      throw Error("Ran out of possibilities");
    }
    pot[i].group = group;
    group.push(pot[i]);
  }
  p++;
}
```

After all this bullshit, how can I make it 100% correct?

**[EDIT] => My problem solved!**

Answer (score 1):

That's a bit too much code for me to dig through to try to understand the issue.  I think you can simplify quite a bit.

For the Champions League, this seems to do the job:

```js
// Champions League
const draw = (pots, nbrOfGroups) => {
  const teams = pots .flatMap ((p, i) => p .map (x => ({...x, pot: i + 1}))) 
    .sort (({country: a}, {country: b}) => a < b ? - 1 : a > b ? 1 : 0)
  const groups = Array .from ({length: nbrOfGroups}, _ => [])
  for (let i = 0; i < teams .length; i++) {
    const team = teams [i]
    const candidateGroups = groups .filter (
      group => group .length < teams .length / nbrOfGroups
            && group .every (member => member.country !== team .country && member .pot !== team.pot)
    )
    if  (candidateGroups .length < 1) return draw (pots, nbrOfGroups) // try over
    candidateGroups [Math.floor (Math .random () * candidateGroups .length)] .push (team)
  }
  return groups
}

const pots = [[{name: "Real Madrid", country: "Spain"}, {name: "Eintracht Frankfurt", country: "Germany"}, {name: "Manchester City", country: "England"}, {name: "AC Milan", country: "Italy"}, {name: "Bayern München", country: "Germany"}, {name: "Paris Saint-Germain", country: "France"}, {name: "FC Porto", country: "Portugal"}, {name: "Ajax", country: "Netherlands"}], [{name: "Liverpool", country: "England"}, {name: "Chelsea", country: "England"}, {name: "FC Barcelona", country: "Spain"}, {name: "Juventus", country: "Italy"}, {name: "Atlético Madrid", country: "Spain"}, {name: "Sevilla", country: "Spain"}, {name: "RB Leipzig", country: "Germany"}, {name: "Tottenham Hotspur", country: "England"}], [{name: "Borussia Dortmund", country: "Germany"}, {name: "FC Salzburg", country: "Austria"}, {name: "Shakhtar Donetsk", country: "Ukraine"}, {name: "Internazionale", country: "Italy"}, {name: "Napoli", country: "Italy"}, {name: "Benfica", country: "Portugal"}, {name: "Sporting CP Lisbon", country: "Portugal"}, {name: "Bayer Leverkusen", country: "Germany"}], [{name: "Glasgow Rangers", country: "Scotland"}, {name: "Dinamo Zagreb", country: "Croatia"}, {name: "Olympique Marseille", country: "France"}, {name: "FC København", country: "Denmark"}, {name: "Club Brugge", country: "Belgium"}, {name: "Celtic", country: "Scotland"}, {name: "Viktoria Plzen", country: "Czechia"}, {name: "Maccabi Haifa", country: "Israel"}]]

console .log (draw (pots, 8))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

We flatten out the `pots` array into `teams`, assigning each team its `pot` number.  Then we create an array of groups, each initially an empty array.  Then for each team, we find all the groups in which it can still fit, by filtering the groups to those that are not already full and for which every member has a different country and different pot from the current one.  If there are no such groups, then our initial assignments cannot work, and we recursively call our `draw` function again.  If there are such groups, we randomly select one, and push our current team into it.

If we've gotten through all the teams, then we have a legal draw.

This only works because there are many possible solutions.  If we were trying to find the only such solution, or to optimize something else about the solution, then we would need a more complex algorithm.  But this is simpler, and in my testing, this most often took a single call, averaged below 1.5 calls, and never reached more than 12 calls, so recursion depth was never an issue.  But if you ever do run into the limit, it's easy enough to call it again.

The draw for the World Cup is even simpler, since we don't have to combine the teams or generate the `pot` properties.  The chief difference is that when we select our candidate groups for each team, instead of testing whether any team is from the same country, we test to ensure that it doesn't include too many from the team's conference (which here means that if the conference is 'UEFA', then we can already have one, otherwise cannot already have any.)

It looks like this:

```js
// World Cup
const draw = (teams, nbrOfGroups) => {
  const groups = Array .from ({length: nbrOfGroups}, _ => [])
  for (let i = 0; i < teams .length; i++) {
    const team = teams [i]
    const candidateGroups = groups .filter (
      group => group .length < teams .length / nbrOfGroups && group .filter (
        member => member .conf == team .conf
      ) .length < (team .conf == "UEFA" ? 2: 1)
    )
    if  (candidateGroups .length < 1) return draw (teams, nbrOfGroups) // try over
    candidateGroups [Math.floor (Math .random () * candidateGroups .length)] .push (team)
  }
  return groups
}

const teams = [{name: "Qatar", conf: "AFC"}, {name: "Brazil", conf: "CONMEBOL"}, {name: "Belgium", conf: "UEFA"}, {name: "France", conf: "UEFA"}, {name: "Argentina", conf: "CONMEBOL"}, {name: "England", conf: "UEFA"}, {name: "Spain", conf: "UEFA"}, {name: "Portugal", conf: "UEFA"}, {name: "Mexico", conf: "CONCACAF"}, {name: "Netherlands", conf: "UEFA"}, {name: "Denmark", conf: "UEFA"}, {name: "Germany", conf: "UEFA"}, {name: "Uruguay", conf: "CONMEBOL"}, {name: "Switzerland", conf: "UEFA"}, {name: "USA", conf: "CONCACAF"}, {name: "Croatia", conf: "UEFA"}, {name: "Senegal", conf: "CAF"}, {name: "IR Iran", conf: "AFC"}, {name: "Japan", conf: "AFC"}, {name: "Morocco", conf: "CAF"}, {name: "Serbia", conf: "UEFA"}, {name: "Poland", conf: "UEFA"}, {name: "Korea Republic", conf: "AFC"}, {name: "Tunisia", conf: "CAF"}, {name: "Cameroon", conf: "CAF"}, {name: "Canada", conf: "CONCACAF"}, {name: "Ecuador", conf: "CONMEBOL"}, {name: "Saudi Arabia", conf: "AFC"}, {name: "Ghana", conf: "CAF"}, {name: "Wales", conf: "UEFA"}, {name: "Costa Rica", conf: "CONCACAF"}, {name: "Australia", conf: "AFC"}]

console .log (draw (teams, 8))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

This does not do the sorting to put Qatar first.  I would do that after grouping the teams, as it makes the individual functions simpler.  One approach is in the following snippet:

```js
// World Cup
const draw = (teams, nbrOfGroups) => {
  const groups = Array .from ({length: nbrOfGroups}, _ => [])
  for (let i = 0; i < teams .length; i++) {
    const team = teams [i]
    const candidateGroups = groups .filter (
      group => group .length < teams .length / nbrOfGroups && group .filter (
        member => member .conf == team .conf
      ) .length < (team .conf == "UEFA" ? 2: 1)
    )
    if  (candidateGroups .length < 1) return draw (teams, nbrOfGroups) // try over
    candidateGroups [Math.floor (Math .random () * candidateGroups .length)] .push (team)
  }
  return groups
}

const compare = (first, a, b) => 
  a == first ? - 1 : b == first ? 1 : a < b ? -1 : b < a ? 1 : 0

const sortGroups = (host) => (teams) => 
  teams .map (team => team .sort (({name: a}, {name: b}) => compare (host, a, b))) 
        .sort (([{name: a}], [{name: b}]) => compare (host, a, b))

const drawAndSort = (teams, host, nbrOfGroups) => 
  sortGroups (host) (draw (teams, nbrOfGroups))

const teams = [{name: "Qatar", conf: "AFC"}, {name: "Brazil", conf: "CONMEBOL"}, {name: "Belgium", conf: "UEFA"}, {name: "France", conf: "UEFA"}, {name: "Argentina", conf: "CONMEBOL"}, {name: "England", conf: "UEFA"}, {name: "Spain", conf: "UEFA"}, {name: "Portugal", conf: "UEFA"}, {name: "Mexico", conf: "CONCACAF"}, {name: "Netherlands", conf: "UEFA"}, {name: "Denmark", conf: "UEFA"}, {name: "Germany", conf: "UEFA"}, {name: "Uruguay", conf: "CONMEBOL"}, {name: "Switzerland", conf: "UEFA"}, {name: "USA", conf: "CONCACAF"}, {name: "Croatia", conf: "UEFA"}, {name: "Senegal", conf: "CAF"}, {name: "IR Iran", conf: "AFC"}, {name: "Japan", conf: "AFC"}, {name: "Morocco", conf: "CAF"}, {name: "Serbia", conf: "UEFA"}, {name: "Poland", conf: "UEFA"}, {name: "Korea Republic", conf: "AFC"}, {name: "Tunisia", conf: "CAF"}, {name: "Cameroon", conf: "CAF"}, {name: "Canada", conf: "CONCACAF"}, {name: "Ecuador", conf: "CONMEBOL"}, {name: "Saudi Arabia", conf: "AFC"}, {name: "Ghana", conf: "CAF"}, {name: "Wales", conf: "UEFA"}, {name: "Costa Rica", conf: "CONCACAF"}, {name: "Australia", conf: "AFC"}]


console .log (drawAndSort (teams, 'Qatar', 8))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort, I really appreciate that,
but actually I already used the recursive algo (using while loop) but anyway the result is the same, my idea is simulating the real draw,
You can find it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2022_FIFA_World_Cup_seeding
so I should do this:
after getting the first available group we should make sure that if this group included that team, this will not affect the rest of the draw,
this is why my code is a little bit large, because we don't want to get any errors.
Anyway a website called Inker do this: https://draw.inker.one.

Comment: It was an interesting problem. Mine was an attempt to simulate the same thing as you described.  Reading that Wikipedia page, there is one miss here: all groups are required to have at least one European team. The code above insists they have no more than two , but doesn't ensure they have at least one. All the runs I checked did so, but I'm sure it could occasionally fail. Also, I didn't have any rule for sorting the teams in the group, so I just did alphabetical (except Qatar.)  That would be easy to change.  Please note that your `shuffle` is badly biased. You might look up Fischer-Yates.

Comment: Oh, thanks again, I usualy use shuffle by random sorting just to make it easier when I need something fast.
And there is a rule for every group, if we divide `x` (Number of qualified teams from some confederation) by `8` (Number of groups) = `y`,
then: `Math.floor(y)` is the minimal number of teams from this confederation per group and `Math.ceil(y)` is the maximum number of teams per group
this is why for Europe there are 13 teams qualified, so 13 / 8 = 1.625 (So minimum: is 1 and maximum is 2).

Comment: Oh, I won't bother changing this, but it would be cleaner to use the `floor`/`ceil` calculation than my "UEFA" hack.  As to the shuffle, [this](http://link.fourwindssoft.com/71) should help to demonstrate its bias.  [More details](https://www.robweir.com/blog/2010/02/microsoft-random-browser-ballot.html).

Comment: Very big thanks,
I really loved this example, this code and the idea behind it gave me a better picture of shuffling, as I saw, the shuffle algo I used, don't result a fare shuffling, unlike the two others, the results repetition were almost equal.